# Difference between Object.keys() and Object.hasOwnProperty()?

Tags: javascript

When testing if an object has a key we can use `Object.keys()` or `Object.hasOwnProperty()`.

Consider an object `{ a: 1 }`.

```
console.log(Object.keys({ a: 1 })); // [ 'a' ]
```

Now, whe I use `Object.hasOwnProperty()` I get `true`:

```
console.log('a' in { a: 1 }); // true

console.log({ a: 1 }.hasOwnProperty('a')); // true
```

But if I use `Object.keys()` I get `false` :

```
console.log('a' in Object.keys({ a: 1 })); // false
```

Why is it `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `Object.keys({ a: 1 })` will return `[ 'a' ]` which is an Array containing the object's keys. This statement will return `false` :

```
console.log('a' in ['a']); // false
```

So you could use :

```
console.log(Object.keys({ a: 1 }).includes('a')); // true
```

But it's more straight forward to simply use :

```
console.log({ a: 1 }.hasOwnProperty('a')); // true
```

Comment: "*This statement will return false…*" because "a" is now a value, not a property name. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Lets see some docs first

The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would. [[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).[[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Now consider an object { a: 1 }.

```
console.log(Object.keys({ a: 1 })); // [ 'a' ]
```

Available keys in array = 'a'

Using Object.hasOwnProperty()

```
console.log({ a: 1 }.hasOwnProperty('a')); // true
```

Is equivalent to

```
const object1 = new Object();
object1.a = 1;
console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('a')) // true
```

Finally, consider this

```
console.log('a' in Object.keys({ a: 1 })); // false
```

With reference to the docs for [in](http://The%20in%20operator%20returns%20true%20if%20the%20specified%20property%20is%20in%20the%20specified%20object%20or%20its%20prototype)

The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain. This is not the same as the prior 2. This is equivalent to

```
console.log('a' in ['a'])
```

which is false since there is no property 'a' in ['a']

i.e.

```
console.log(['a'].hasOwnProperty('a')); // returns false
```